# Messy with the definition of Adaptive Server Enterprise

Tags: sybase

I am using sybase as the database. And i want to connect my application to the sybase.

what is the purpose of adaptive server enterprise? i think i am using oledb to connect. So i am confused what is the purpose of using adaptive server enterprise?

What is adaptive server enterprise in simple term?

Comment: Your question may be too broad. Please be specific on what is your problem instead of asking opinion on what ASE is.

Comment: Adaptive server enterprise allow both oledb and odbc connection method?

Comment: Yes, depends on the version/release.